# UITableViewRow displays Buttons without Color

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I a have 2 Buttons within my custom TableViewCell.
The Buttons are in bright colors. (BackgroundColor set)

[image]

However: Running the app - The Buttons color disappear and it becomes white:

[image]

I tried to programmatically change the color in `viewDidLoad` but Xcode doesn't react.

Any Ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you want to see? as mentioned the code didn't work. I put them as outlets and changed the background color with `        cell.noButton.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
`

Comment: The problem must be in the IB, i guess..

Comment: @JVS Why are you setting the layer background color and not just the view background color?

Comment: Right, you should be able to just say cell.noButton.backGroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

Comment: thanks a lot. didn't see that one coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heart of the problem is that you have introduced buttons but you are also setting the cell's `textLabel!.text`. You can't mix and match like that. If you're going to use a custom cell, you must use a *completely* custom cell.

Set the cell's type to Custom, drag a label into it, use a custom cell class, give it an outlet to the label, set *this* label's text, and all will be well.

Here's my custom cell with an outlet:

```
class MyCell : UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var label : UILabel!
}
```

Here's my `cellForRow`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCell
    cell.label.text = "Hi" // NOT cell.textLabel!.text
    return cell
}
```

As you can see, the result is that button appears just fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra word in there:

```
cell.noButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

Comment: How does this explain why any code is needed at all? Why isn't the button color in the storyboard the button color when the app runs?